# Why is "what's what?" always wrong as a question?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, interrogatives, informal-language, australian-english

When I talk to somebody, and I miss a certain part(word) of the sentence they said, I have a habit of replacing the unheard part with *what* and ask the same sentence like this:

> Speaker: Can you please pass the texta(missed)?
>   Me: Can you pass **what**?
>
> Speaker: Why don't you drink coffee(missed) in the morning?
>   Me: Why don't you drink **what** in the morning(what-in-the-morning is spoken with a special intonation).
>
> Speaker: What is the time(missed)?
>   Me: What is **what**?

The speaker I was talking to was an English guy, and he said you can't say *what's what*.

What is grammatically wrong with *what's what* as a question and why can I replace the unheard word with *what* in other sentences?

Thank you.

Comment: He's wrong, pretty much, though the confusion may be from you not including "the", so instead of "What's the *what*?" you said "What's *what*?" Both are correct, though. A politer way of requesting someone to repeat what they said would be "Pardon?" (pronounced "par" as in golf, "duhn" as in garden)

Comment: Note: where Corsaka uses italic font, e.g. "He said _what_?", that word is spoken with emphasis.